# How to validate the single column values are in alphabetical order of webtable in c# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, specflow

**Premise:**

I have a web table with three columns. I need to verify if in the second column the first names of all the employees are in alphabetical order.

Also on top of the web table I have a search option, and I need to verify if when I search a namen and click search all,  the names come out starting with the one searched.

I'm doing it in c#, selenium, spec flow NUnit.

**Question:**

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: We do not have enough information to help you. Please [edit] your question to include a [repro].

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate trought all rows and collect text into list.

```
List<String> li = new List<String>();

for (int i=0; i<driver.findelement(By.xpath("/table/tbody[1]/tr")).size();i++)
{
li.add(driver.findelement(By.xpath("/table/tbody[1]/tr["+i+"]/td[2]")).getText());
}
List<String> li2 = new List<String>();
li2 = li.Sort();  //you need to have deep copy here (not sure that this is)
```

After that you can compare every element of these two list in for loop.

Comment: Once the names are in a list, you can simply verify that the list is in order using `Assert.That(li, Is.Ordered);`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that this is your table below.

Add your using calls:

```
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Then you want to find your elements for each row. In this one we find the FirstName. This will add all values with the element of the first name to your list. It will then compare the original to the sorted and they should be equal. If you change the element to find the last name, it will fail because "Smith" is on row one and "Abbot" is on line 2 and it will not be alphabetical.

```
        List<String> item = new List<string>();
        // grab the cells that contain the value you want to sort
        IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> cells = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//td[@id='fn']"));
        // loop through the and assign the name into the 
        foreach (IWebElement cell in cells)
        {
            item.Add(cell.Text);
        }
        List<string> listDefault = item.ToList();
        List<string> listSorted = listDefault.OrderBy(x => x).ToList(); //sort list asc to compare
        Assert.IsTrue(listDefault.SequenceEqual(listSorted));
```

The Table:

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table style="width:25%">
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="fn">Robert</td>
            <td id="ln">Smith</td>
            <td id="age">25</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="fn">Sally</td>
            <td id="ln">Abbot</td>
            <td id="age">24</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        </body>
```